# Print property name (not what you would think)

Tags: c#

This is a cursory question I can't quite answer.

The main program

```
class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        Util.Print(myClass.Id);
        Util.Print(myClass.Server);
        Util.Print(myClass.Ping);
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }   
}
```

How do I implement the Util.Print method to get this output to the console:

```
Begin
Id
Server
Ping
End
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to use strings, the most common answer is via an `Expression` - essentially emulating the missing `infoof`; you would have to use something like:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Begin");
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    Util.Print(() => myClass.Id);
    Util.Print(() => myClass.Server);
    Util.Print(() => myClass.Ping);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
```

Assuming they are all properties/fields (**edit** added method-call support):

```
 public static class Util
{
    public static void Print<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        WriteExpression(expr);
    }
    public static void Print(Expression<Action> expr) // for "void" methods
    {
        WriteExpression(expr);
    }
    private static void WriteExpression(Expression expr)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)expr;
        switch (lambda.Body.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                Console.WriteLine(((MemberExpression)lambda.Body)
                    .Member.Name);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Call:
                Console.WriteLine(((MethodCallExpression)lambda.Body)
                    .Method.Name);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 at first glance i didn't really think he could do something like this, but i totally forgot about expression trees and reading the data from the tree.  Great...

Comment: +1 Expressions == code as data!  Nicely done.

Comment: What a kick ass response. Thanx a million

Comment: That.... is very interesting.  Anyone have a good link for a primer on these "Expression Trees"?

Comment: @GWLlosa - that was a question this week... I'm having difficulty finding it, though

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Marc's answer: [here is an article](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html) which explains several ways to do what you want to do (one such method uses expressions).

Answer (score -1):

```
public string Id {
    get {
      return "Id;"
    }
}
```

Hehe erm, though I assume that's not what you mean :-( The answer will likely be something to do with reflection.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx

Comment: -1 this doesn't really answer the OPs question.  I think he's really looking for something that can accept any random property

Comment: +1, this kind of answer highlights the ambiguity in the OP question and promotes editing for clarification through peer pressure.

Comment: I was gonna rate this down, but I agree with the comment above me.  OP should really clarify.  I was kinda confused.